# Using initWithObjects: causes crash, but initWithCapacity: followed by addObject: does not

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, exc-bad-access, storyboard

A really strange problem. I have to init an array in  `- (void)viewDidLoad`.

The array, `prjMemberArray` is declared as a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* prjMemberArray;
```

If I use this

```
prjMemberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"someone",@"someone",@"someone" ,nil];
```

with `release` called in  `viewDidUnload`,

then when the view loaded , it will crashes immediately But when I use this:

```
prjMemberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

[prjMemberArray addObject:@"someone"];
```

it works well. Can anyone explain this?  I use a storyboard to present the current view controller, like this:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];  
prj_Detail = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProjectDetailVC"]; 

[self presentModalViewController:prj_Detail animated:YES];
```

Where `prjMemberArray` is a property of `prj_Detail`.

Comment: Are you actually adding literal strings to the array (`@"someone"`), or other objects?

Comment: Yes, I suspect you're leaving out some critical details.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have not misspelled items and written e.g. `"someone"` instead of `@"someone"` in the crashing scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use **self** when referring to properties. Here's the a safe way to declare that without having to worry about leaks:

Header:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* prjMemberArray;
```

Implementation:

```
@synthesize prjMemberArray=_prjMemberArray;

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *prjMemberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"someone", @"someone", @"someone" ,nil];

    self.prjMemberArray = prjMemberArray;

    [prjMemberArray release];
}

- (void) dealloc {

    [_prjMemberArray release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

@property creates the getter and setter for your variable but is often confused for a variable itself.  When they released XCode4 I believe they added the ability to set what you want the instance variable to be named by doing:

```
@synthesize prjMemberArray=_prjMemberArray;
```

Before XCode4 you simply did:

```
@synthesize prjMemberArray;
```

So what @property is doing behind the scenes is a little something like this:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) prjMemberArray {
    return _prjMemberArray;
}

-(void) setPrjMemberArray:(NSMutableArray *) val {
    if( _prjMemberArray != nil )
        [prjMemberArray release];

    _prjMemberArray = [val retain];
}
```

So don't think of @property as a variable itself and remember to always use **self** when referring to them.  That should save you a lot of pain and a few memory leaks as well.

Comment: `prjMemberArray` can't be released as it's autoreleased.

Comment: There ya go, the main point is to always use self when referring to properties.